# Separater service between 2 users in API Gateway

Tags: microservices

so, I have a route in my API, more or less like this:

/ api / item / create 
   / api / item / list 
   / api / item / detail

and I want to install services on the Gateway API like Kong.
in my application, there are 2 types of users say guest and registered. where guest users cannot access route / create ..
how should I make a service?

because based on design, one service has 2 different treatments depending on the route accessed. do I need to make two services

Comment: You can keep the single end point and restrict the actions that are only for authorized users. You may be using controllers at backend so just put restrictions on actions. But you will have to put authentication in place.

Comment: okay, so it's better to do a separation on the controller than to change the route? because features like this are not just one but all items that have route create.

`api/item2/create` 
`api/item2/list` 

`api/item3/create` 
`api/item3/list`

Comment: If the context of item belong to same controller then don't make 2 endpoints. Create all the action using same route and secure the one you want to authorize. e.g.user CRUD operation should go to same controller.  If you want to secure any of the action you can do it in same controller.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,
if each route goes to a different controller?
`api / item2 / create -> controller A`
`api / item2 / list -> controller A1`
api / item3 / create -> controller B
`api / item3 / list -> controller B1`

I thought about separating route `/ create` and making it a separate service from route `/ list` , etc.

Comment: One of the Rest principle states that there should be only on route to explore the resource. So having one api where i can do all sort of operations on that particular resource. It's really upto you how you want to do it.